# Android Toggle Button state changes on scrolling listview

Tags: android

Iam new to android . i have a toggle button in a listview and by default it should show on state !but it is showing off and on clicking the button state changes but on scrolling the view state is not retained.

My list view look like below:
            Bill No                 1234
            Booking Date            2013-06-13
            Invoice Number          123
            Port of Loading         df
            Port of Destination     ys
            Alert                   ToggleButton unchecked ie off state

My listviewadapter class

```
private class listviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;
        Activity activity;
        SparseBooleanArray mSparseBooleanArray;

        public listviewAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super();
            this.activity = activity;
            this.list = list;
            mSparseBooleanArray = new SparseBooleanArray(list.size());
        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }



        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ListViewHolder viewHolder;
            LayoutInflater inflater =  activity.getLayoutInflater();
            final int pos = position;
            if (convertView == null)
            {
                convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row_list1,null);
                txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.FirstText);
                txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.SecondText);
                togglbtn=(ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tglbtn1);
                 togglbtn.setTag(position);
                 togglbtn.setChecked(mSparseBooleanArray.get(position));
                 togglbtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckedChangeListener);
                convertView.setTag( new ListViewHolder(txtFirst,txtSecond,togglbtn));

            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                txtFirst = viewHolder.getText1();
                txtSecond = viewHolder.getText2();
                togglbtn =  viewHolder.getButton();



            }

            HashMap<String, String> map = list.get(position);
        //  count=count+6;
            txtFirst.setTypeface(font1);
            txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
            txtSecond.setTypeface(font2);
            txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
            String data= map.get(FIRST_COLUMN);
            String value_data=map.get(SECOND_COLUMN);

                if(data.trim().equals("HBL NO"))
                {
                    convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.LightBlue);
                }
                else
                {
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                }

                if(data.trim().equals("ALERT"))
                {
                    togglbtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    /*if(value_data.trim().equals("YES"))
                    {

                        togglbtn.setChecked(true);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        togglbtn.setChecked(false);
                    }*/
                }
                else
                {
                    togglbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }





            return convertView;

        }

     public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mSparseBooleanArray.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mSparseBooleanArray.put(position, isChecked);

        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));

        }

        OnCheckedChangeListener mCheckedChangeListener=new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("Tag: "+buttonView.getTag());
                mSparseBooleanArray.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(),
                        isChecked);
                System.out.println("Status: "+isChecked);

            }
        };


    }

    private static class ListViewHolder 
    {
        private TextView txt1 ;
        private TextView txt2 ;
        private ToggleButton btn;
        int ref;

        //public ListViewHolder() {}
        public ListViewHolder(TextView tx1,TextView tx2,ToggleButton btn) {
            this.txt1=tx1 ;
            this.txt2=tx2 ;
            this.btn=btn;
        }
        public TextView getText1() {
            return txt1;
        }
        public TextView getText2() {
            return txt2;
        }

        public ToggleButton getButton()
        {
            return btn;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a lot of code. Please narrow it down to where you think the problem is happening.

Comment: Looks like you `boolean` values in Sparse... changes state to **true**

Answer (score 1):

Just add this two methods in your Adapter class it will work fine

```
       @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {                 
           return yourlist.size();
        }
       @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int pos)
           return pos;
        }
```